# Can't get my api to work in Postman, POST returns 404 . its a vue frontend and express backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, vuejs3

I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.bezkoder.com/node-express-mongodb-crud-rest-api/) and I'm stuck at the end. getting 404's in postman when using POST with this URL `http://localhost:5050/api/projects` its been 3 days any one know what I'm doing wrong?
**server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const PORT = 5050;
// Connect to the database
require("./src/server/database/connection");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
var corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:5051"
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(express.json());
// parse requests of content-type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
// simple route
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "Code Wire Server." });
});

require("./src/server/routes/routes")(app);
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening at http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

**connection.js**
How to connect to the database

```
const db = require("../model/index.js");
db.mongoose
  .connect(db.url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to the database!");
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log("Cannot connect to the database!", err);
    process.exit();
  });
```

**index.js**

```
const dbConfig = require("../config/db.config.js");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const db = {};
db.mongoose = mongoose;
db.url = dbConfig.url;
db.project = require("./projects_db.js")(mongoose);
module.exports = db;
```

**db.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  url: "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/code-wire-db"
}
```

**projects_db.js**
A database schema for my project I'm working on

```
module.exports = mongoose => {
  var schema = mongoose.Schema({
    project_title: String,
    description: String,
  } );
  schema.method("toJSON", function() {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    const { __v, _id, ...object } = this.toObject();
    object.id = _id;
    return object;
  });
  const projectsDB = mongoose.model("projectsDB", schema);
  return projectsDB;
```

**projects_controller.js**

```
const db = require("../model/index");
const project = db.project;

// Create and Save a new project
exports.create = (req, res) => {
  // Validate request
  if (!req.body.title) {
    res.status(400).send({ message: "Content can not be empty!" });
    return;
  }
  // Create a project
  const Project = new project({
    project_title: req.body.project_title,
    description: req.body.description
  });
  // Save project in the database
  Project
    .save(Project)
    .then(data => {
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message:
          err.message || "Some error occurred while creating the Project."
      });
    });
};
```

**routes.js**

```
module.exports = app => {
  const projects = require("../controller/projects_controller.js");
  var router = require("express").Router();
  // Create a new project
  router.post("/", projects.create);
  
  app.use('/api/projects', router);
};
```

Comment: What does `./src/server/routes/routes` routes look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
[![problem][1]][1]

See that return symbol, I found out 4 days later that means there is 2 lines or more. Meaning postman was sending 2 lines instead of one. With no error message
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVlha.jpg